# Retire a domain

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

We have a domain foo.com which was pointing to our main site bar.com (same IP address) Different content rendered for foo.com and bar.com

We have decided to retire foo.com. For the last while all foo requests have been 301 redirected to bar.com

Foo.com never built up much domain authority, so not sure if any value to the 301

We would like to formally retire foo.com and stop 301 redirecting all content to the equivalent bar.com page.

We could just change DNS to point to some holding page.

Is this a good idea. Anyone think we are deriving any link juice benefit from the inbound foo.com links?

Comment: It is impossible for us to know about your sites link profile and to comment on foo.com. However, if you find there is no value in foo.com, just let it go. Delete it if you do not need it. People often worry too much over domain names with no value. If foo.com has value, then you need to consider what to do with it. Only you can tell us if foo.com has value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no major links pointing to foo.com or if the site doesn't get too much of direct traffic, then you can safely let it go.

Answer (score 1):

Before removing the old domain redirect to the new site, I would double check which are the website main traffic sources.

If there are relevant links in other websites pointing to the old domain, then it could make sense to keep the old domain or consider if losing it is just fine.